# Help getting TED working and having it integrated with dash/menu

Tags: java, bittorrent, jdk

I have installed latest JDK 1.7.0_u1 using the method provided at this page  [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-jdk-in.html)

Now i need help to get Torrent Episode Download Running .. I'm noob in these matters please help me and guide me with step by step instructions.

I have downloaded the zip file from TED site
double clicking on the jar file opens it in file roller

running the command java ted.jar or java jar ted.jar gine me some error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class .home.sarvesh.TED.ted.jar
```

and

```
Error: Could not find or load main class jar
```

please help me
any apps that can help me download torrents using rss feeds also appreciated [please leave out vuze its too complicated and resource heavy] ... but i will prefer sticking with transmission

also can some one guide me with having this app shownup in dash so i can open it from gnoome do and via classic menu indicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
java -jar /home/sarvesh/TED/ted.jar
```

note the dash before the -jar option and also using of / instead of . to separate directories in the path.

Comment: can you also tell me how to have this app included in the menu ?
as in if i type it in dash it should show up anlso in gnomedo and the classic menu indicator